# Import Polymer 2 components in Polymer 3

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-3.x

I am developing a web component using Polymer v3, and need to include some custom elements defined in legacy Polymer 2 components in the template HTML of my new component.

Since HTML imports are no longer supported in Polymer 3, what approach should I take to include them? If I was using Polymer 2 I could just add the following in my component's HTML file:

```
<link rel="import" href="../my-legacy-component.html">
```

I have tried adding the above link into the template HTML of my component, but it appears that doesn't work. I have also tried various `import` commands to reference the JS files inside the legacy component directly, but received various inscrutable JS errors so I'm not sure if that is the correct way to go either.

I can't believe there isn't a simple way to do this - would the Polymer team really introduce a new version of the library that is completely incompatible with all the components created using older versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to use polymer-modulizer?
Modulizer performs many different upgrade tasks, like:

- Detects which .html files are used as HTML Imports and moves them to .js
- Rewrites  in HTML to import in JS.
- Removes "module wrappers" - IIFEs that scopes your code.
- Converts bower.json to package.json, using the corresponding packages on npm.
- Converts "namespace references" to the proper JS module import, ie: Polymer.Async.timeOut to timeOut as imported from @polymer/polymer/lib/util/async.
- Creates exports for values assigned to namespace referencs. ie, Foo.bar = {...} becomes export const bar = {...}
- Rewrites namespace objects - an object with many members intended to be used as a module-like object, to JS modules.
- Moves Polymer element templates from HTML into a JS template string.
- Removes s if they only contained a template.
- Moves other generic HTML in the document into a JS string and creates it when the module runs.

[more on github](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-modulizer)

Comment: Thanks, yes I looked at that - when I tried to run it I got an error saying that the module 'js-yaml' could not be found, seems like that utility isn't all that robust

Comment: Ok, I raised a bug on their github and it was fixed within 12 hours(!) So this might be a viable option but I don't really like the idea of having to rewrite the source code of a component to get it to work, it would be much nicer if the framework itself supported importing legacy components.

Comment: None of the rewrites in HTML to import in JS works on my end using this tool, have to do that by hand on everything

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into the same problem with the module `js-yaml` earlier. I don't have enough reputation for a comment yet so I just write it down here.

1. Run this `sudo npm install -g js-yaml` -> This will install the missing package for the tool
2. Then at the root of your project, run `modulizer --import-style name --out .` -> This will convert your component from Polymer 2 to Polymer 3. The option `--import-style name` tells the tool to use package name instead of path. `--out` will make the tool writes those files to the directory.
3. After that, if no error prompts. Try to serve it with `polymer serve --module-resolution=node` -> Since we are using node modules now, we have to provide the `--module-resolution=node` option.

Comment: Thanks, I've raised this as an issue on their github project, if you want to add any information it's here: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-modulizer/issues/436

Comment: Yeah. I guess it was some fat-fingering issue.